# MATLAB Invalid use of operator error message

Tags: matlab, datatable, signals, curve-fitting, data-fitting

The error lies in the line of

```
myfittype = fittype("A*cos(omega_0*t+phi)",dependent="A" "omega_0" "phi",independent="t",coefficients=["A" "omega_0" "phi"]);
```

The following error message appears:

```
File: TOungedsurfacefit.m Line: 15 Column: 58
Invalid use of operator.
```

I added a semicolon as suggested in the line error fix message, but it didn't change anything the datatype of s & t is doubles & they are both 400x1 matrices aka vertically imported column vectors in the workspace. Also I saw, that there was a missing closure bracket, but I added that too & still the error occurred. How to proceed? I would be grateful for any further help! I am a beginner in matlab and dont know anything unfortunately.

```
    p=pi;
    T= 3.95;
    omega_0 = (2*p)/T;
    fo = fitoptions('Method','NonlinearLeastSquares','Lower',[-500,500],'Upper',[Inf,max(s)],'StartPoint',[-500,500]);
     %alternative:fo = fitoptions('Method','NonlinearLeastSquares','Lower',[-500,500],'Upper',[Inf,max(s)],'StartPoint',[-500,500]);   
    x = t;  
    y = s;  
    myfittype = fittype("A*cos(omega_0*t+phi)",dependent="A" "omega_0" "phi",independent="t",coefficients=["A" "omega_0" "phi"]);
    myfit = fit(t',myfittype);
    plot(myfit,t);
    xdft = fft(t); 
    camp = 2/length(t)*xdft(t);     
    phi = angle(camp); 
    A= abs(camp);
```

In general, t is the x value & s is the y value accordingly. I have imported the data table as column vectors.

Comment: You need to provide code that shows the error + the error message. The error message tells you exactly where the error is, its the most important part of the info if you want help.

Comment: Thank you Ander for pointing out the missing part. I have edited the question & added the error! I am looking forward for your help!

Comment: `dependent="A" "omega_0" "phi"` is not valid MATLAB syntax.  Have you checked the documentation? You seem to be missing `[]`

Comment: “Line 15” of the code you posted doesn’t reach to column 58. Why don’t you make a [mre], rather than copy-pasting the bit of code you think is relevant? Then the error message will exactly match the code you post. Also, MATLAB prints out much more for an error message than what you show. it copies the line that the error occurs at and points out the location on the line. Please copy-paste the **full** error message.

Comment: @AnderBiguri %I can't find any more complex example in the documentation for the syntax. %the only example that was given is.x = linspace(1,100);  
y = 7*log(x+5);
myfittype = fittype("a*log(x+b)",...
    dependent="y",independent="x",...
    coefficients=["a" "b"])   %hence I dont know why its not working. I tried to put brackets over it in the following ways:myfittype = fittype("A*cos(omega_0*t+phi)",dependent=["A" "omega_0" "phi"],independent="t",coefficients=["A" "omega_0" "phi"]);

Comment: @Ander as well as myfittype = fittype("A*cos(omega_0*t+phi)",dependent=["A" "omega_0" "phi"],independent=["t"],coefficients=["A" "omega_0" "phi"]);
but either way I get the message "error in line 17" without further specifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using MATLAB's named arguments and string types, which are not the most standard use of MATLAB (not your fault, you are using the docs).

The correct syntax is:

```
myfittype = fittype("A*cos(omega_0*t+phi)",dependent=["A", "omega_0", "phi"],independent="t",coefficients=["A", "omega_0", "phi"]);
```

When in doubt, always add the commas and brackets around arrays.

This still errors because you can't use `A` for both a coefficient and a dependent variable.